# Set difference of an open set and a closed set

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $A$ is an open set and $B$ a closed set. Is it necessarily true that $A \backslash  B$ open? I have thought about a few counter examples but could not come up with any, so I am inclined to say it is true. For example, $\mathbb{R} \backslash \phi$ is both open and closed but this does not impose any problem.

If $A \subset B$ then $A \backslash B = \phi$ which is open. If $A$ and $B$ do not intersect each other then $A \backslash B = A$ which is of course open. The only edge case is when $B \subset A$, which again I think should make $A \backslash  B$ open. Am I right?

Comment: Intersection of finite number of open set is always open.
Recall that $A\setminus B=A\cap B^c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSEWR ACCORDING COMMENT:

Take $A=(-2,2)$ and $C_n=[-1+1/n,1-1/n]$.

Then $B=\bigcup C_n=(-1,1)$ and $A\setminus B=(-2,-1]\cup[1,2)$.

FIRST ANSWER:

You're not right. You missed the genereal case when $A\cap B\ne\varnothing$ but neither $A\subset B$ nor $B\subset A$.

A better approach:
Recall that $A\setminus B=A\cap B^c$ and take into account that intersection of finite number of open set is always open.

Comment: what if $B$ is a countable union of sets? I don't think it makes a difference.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I suppose $B = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} C_n$ where each $C$ is closed.

Comment: So $B$ needs not to be closed!!!

Comment: @Rob, You'll better edit your question

Comment: got it! no worries, you answered my main question. and I understand if $B = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}C_i$ where each $C_i$ is closed and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then your answers still goes through, that is $A \backslash B$ is open.

Comment: but $B = \bigcup_{i=1}^n C_i$ is finite and hence closed.